# Firebase V9 nested objects vs nested collections

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create an inventory system that adds items with the ability to have multiple copies. I want to check the entire database to ensure that no barCodes are duplicated.

### Types

```js
type LibraryItem = {
  item: Item
  copies: LibraryCopy[]
  totalTimesCheckedOut: number
  dateTimeAddedUtc?: string
}

type LibraryCopy = {
  barCode: string
  owner?: Person | 'Library' | string
  checkedOut: boolean
}

type PlayToWinItem = {
  eventKey?: string // might be null if recurring
  eventName?: string // might be null if recurring

  item: Item

  copies?: PlayToWinCopies[]

  isRecurring: boolean
  isDisabled: boolean

  dateTimeAddedUtc?: string
}

type PlayToWinCopies = {
  barCode: string
}
```

### Current DB call

```js
await addDoc(collection(FirebaseFirestore(), 'library-games'), data)
```

My issue comes to the client side. I want to make sure no bar codes are duplicated. Is there a way to query across multiple collections to ensure that

### Database screenshots

[image: Library Games]
[image: Play to win games]

I came across [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) for collection groups and I think it's relevant I'm curious if my issue is how I'm saving the data vs adding it into a new collection.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure a unique value across Firestore, you'll need to:

1. [Run a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) across all docs that may contain that barcode.
2. Then add the document only when you get no results.

With these notes:

- If the documents may exist in multiple collections of the same name, [using collection group queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) would indeed be the way to go.
- Since the second step depends on the result of the first step, you'll want perform both steps in a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions).
- The transaction should likely be combined with security rules that ensure malicious clients can't implement the write operation without a transaction.

---

You'll often find that the above approach is going to be error prone, so a more common way to implement this is by having an extra collection where:

- You use the barcode as the ID of each document
- In the content of that document, identify the actual `library-games` document that "owns" the barcode.

With this in place, you'll then always write two documents in the above transactionL

1. The `library-games` document you already write today.
2. The new `barcode ID` document, which identifies the owner of each barcode and ensures its uniqueness.

The most common use-case for this pattern is in ensuring unique user names, so I also recommend having a look at [questions about that](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+firestore+unique+username)